# Postman - How to preserve double quotes in global variable as part new API Call

Tags: postman

I have the following postman javascript:

```
// Parse the response body as JSON 
var response = JSON.parse (responseBody);
// Create an empty array to store the id values 
var ids = [];
// Loop through each item in the response array 
response.response.forEach (function (item) {ids.push (item.id); });
// Log the ids array to the console 
console.log (ids);
// Set the ids array as a global variable 
pm.globals.set ("ids", ids);
console.log(pm.environment.get("ids"));
```

When I try to use the ids global variable inside the **Post request body** of another API call, like this

```
{ 
 "name" : "show ver and show inventory",
 "commands" : ["show ver", "show inventory"],
 "deviceUuids" : [{{ids}}]
}
```

I get the *bad request error, There was an error processing the input arguments*.

and the request body in the console log shows like this:

```
{ 
 "name" : "show ver and show inventory",
 "commands" : ["show ver", "show inventory"],
 "deviceUuids" : [0a6602ef-2416-4702-a40b-c79308c8a489,85c7a7c4-c578-46d3-9a4b-b84dc6b2a25e,c5ed30a3-9c21-4e01-b70b-2621b8bc09ad,dd1700bc-4310-47c8-a1f9-e2f5840838b5]
}
```

Instead of being like this, which is what I need:

```
{ 
 "name" : "show ver and show inventory",
 "commands" : ["show ver", "show inventory"],
 "deviceUuids" : ["0a6602ef-2416-4702-a40b-c79308c8a489", "85c7a7c4-c578-46d3-9a4b-b84dc6b2a25e", "c5ed30a3-9c21-4e01-b70b-2621b8bc09ad", "dd1700bc-4310-47c8-a1f9-e2f5840838b5"]
}
```

Comment: When I check the postman console  log corresponding to the first the first API call, I can see the global variable store properly as:

["0a6602ef-2416-4702-a40b-c79308c8a489", "85c7a7c4-c578-46d3-9a4b-b84dc6b2a25e", "c5ed30a3-9c21-4e01-b70b-2621b8bc09ad", "dd1700bc-4310-47c8-a1f9-e2f5840838b5"]

If I copy and paste this directly in the second request body of the second API call (which is a POST). Then it works, but I don't want to do manually, just import the global variable into the request body with the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.

in the POST api call, I added the following javascript code to the Tests tab to convert the "ids" global variable to a string (idsString).

```
// Get the global variable `ids`
var ids = pm.globals.get("ids");
// Convert the `ids` array to a string with double quotes around each element
var idsString = JSON.stringify(ids);
// Set the `idsString` variable as a global variable
pm.globals.set("idsString", idsString);
// Log the `idsString` variable to the console
console.log(idsString);
```

And adjusted the post request body to this (idsString is already including the brackets):

```
{ 
 "name" : "show ver and show inventory",
 "commands" : ["show ver", "show inventory"],
 "deviceUuids" : {{idsString}}
}
```